# Number of Notes.ini variable in each release?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

Can any one tell me the exact list of Notes.ini variables for every notes/domino release ?

Got a list based on the category when i searched in Google.

[Link](http://www.lntoolbox.com/en/notesini-reference/bycategory.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of a public definitive list beyond what you have linked.

You can check the following site for Notes.ini settings added against public SPRs.

http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/Notes.ini?OpenView

Also you may find others by looking for "[Ask Professor INI](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/lotus/libraryview.jsp?sort_by=&show_abstract=true&show_all=&search_flag=&contentarea_by=Lotus&search_by=Ask%20Professor%20INI&product_by=-1&topic_by=-1&industry_by=-1&type_by=All%20Types&ibm-search=Search)" in developerworks (very old though, so no recent ini settings).

Comment: I'm sure there are undocumented settings as well, since I've encountered some over the years (they were recommended to us, but there was no documentation out there saying they existed).

Comment: Hence the reason they are called undocumented. :)  Normally they are put in for debugging reasons. The debug created is generally useless except to IBM development, and may or may not be there in a later release/fix pack.